Runtimes of FIR for various number formats
I read ST's application note regarding the implementation of DSP operations using their dedicated DSP HW using CMSIS implementation.
They compare performance for an FFT and an FIR filter, each using 3 number formats: floating-point, fixed-point Q15, and fixed-point Q31.
I assumed the floating point would be the slowest and Q15 would be the fastest. However, their benchmarking show (image below) that Q15 is indeed the fastest for FFT, but float32 is faster than Q31.

For an FIR filter (image below), float32 is the fastest and Q15 is the slowest. Could you please explain these results? Why would a floating point beat a fixed point? Does it mean their FPU is simply better than their integer MAC hardware?


"They compare performance for an FFT and an FIR filter, which both run at floating-point Q15 or Q31 formats." - - - Don't you mean fixed-point here?  I have never seen floating-point format referred to as Q15 or Q31.

@robertbristow-johnson my phrasing was bad. I fixed it.


Why would a floating point beat a fixed point?

Many processors these days have single cycle multiply (or add, sub accu, etc.) instructions for both data types. In this case floating point is indeed faster since most algorithms can be more efficiently implemented in floating point. Fixed point typically requires some extra "overhead": scaling, Q-shifting, clip detection/prevention, etc. which comes "build-in" with floating point.

Does it mean their FPU is simply better than their integer MAC hardware?

Maybe? I think in this case the FPU is separate from the to the CPU to technically the CPU can do something else, while the FPU is chewing on the floating point data, which could speed up looping or data fetching. But that really depends on how the whole system is laid out.
For may DSP algorithms the limiting factor is not necessarily the number of arithmetic operations but data throughput. For an FFT you need to load a complex number and a twiddle factor before you can do a Butterfly. If the FPU has a dedicated memory access path, this may indeed be faster.
Q15 in a 32-bit processor is a bit of an oddball. Typically you pack two 16-bit words into a 32 bit register or memory location. If you have the right instruction set, you can take advantage of this, but if you manually need to unpack the 16-bit numbers, it will slow you down.

I don't have much of an explanation for the FIR performance.
Their time consumption amount appears at first to not be scaled directly to the machine cycles.  But they are directly proportional, since it's a log(time) scale, the difference between blue and maroon is constant in the log domain.
Perhaps there are optimized butterfly instructions for 16-bit words, but for doing an FIR in a straight-forward manner, there are small costs in casting the 32-bit result from a multiply back to a 16-bit word.  Likely the barrel shifter needs an instruction that you might not need for 32-bit or for float arithmetic.  But I'm just speculating.
I just took a look at the document and this Figure 3 is just stupid.  Why would they confuse people like that?

If I had a good 'n fast 32-bit machine (with 32$\times$32 bit = 64 bit accumulator) I would have, for a default scale, 4 bits left of the binary point and 28 bits to the right. Range is -8.0 to +7.9999999 and you have better precision than single-precision IEEE-754.

I don’t get why the figure 3 in stupid? Can you elaborately?

@YairM ,  no one is doing 24 bits for the integer part and only 8 bits for the fractional part.  That scaling format is totally useless for the processing of fixed-point signals.  If you have 32 bits, you want to keep at least 24 bits as the fractional part so that you have decent fractional precision with coefficients and such.  I recommend 4 or maybe 5 bits for the signed integer part and 28 or maybe 27 bits for the unsigned fractional part.  That means that the 32-bit integer value is scaled up by $2^{24}$ or $2^{23}$ from the true mathematical meaning of the value. That's the best way.

Now, maybe if you're converting or quantizing 32-bit fixed to 24-bit fixed, the quantization point will be at the bit 8 position of the word.  In fact that is something that I am doing right now (but I am first scaling and casting float to int32_t then I am quantizing the most-significant 24 bits to the nearest multiple of 0x00000100 using fraction saving.  Perhaps that's what they meant in that document.
